Ошибка в запросе к БД SQLite
Хочу обновить две таблицы Readers и Persons в одном запросе.
UPDATE Readers r
JOIN Persons p ON r.PersonalId = p.Id
SET r.libraryCardNumber = 150, r.TotalBooks = 8, p.Firstname = 'Имя', 
p.Lastname = 'Фамилия', p.Surname = 'Отчество', p.DateOfBirth = '01.01.01'
WHERE r.Id = 48

Выдает ошибку Execution finished with errors. Result: near "r": syntax error At line 1: UPDATE Readers r
Если сделать запрос без сокращений вроде r и p, то ошибка будет Execution finished with errors.Result: near "JOIN": syntax error At line 1: UPDATE Readers JOIN
Что неправильно?

«обновить две таблицы» — SQLite так в принципе не умеет

Обновить несколько таблиц в одном выражении невозможно в SQLite.
